# Trying to understand nested loops, identity matrix

Tags: python

So I am stuck on nested loops, I feel like I understand them about half the time and then I start to work on a different problem and then I don't understand them anymore.  Maybe I am over complicating things.  Anyways back to my problem, I have an identity matrix

```
lst = [[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1]]
```

I am trying to write a program that will check to see if it is an identity matrix,  so I know that the index where i and j are have the same index(i.e i at position 0 and j at position 0; i at position 1 and j at position 1; i at position 2 and j at position 2) and are equal to 1 then the matrix is the identity matrix.  Now my problem is I feel like I struggle articulating this to a computer.  Or in other words `lst[0][0], lst[1][1] and lst[2][2]` should all equal 1 and all the other values should equal zero.  Without giving me the answer can someone maybe nudge me in the right direction?  I've been trying to solve this for about 2 weeks now I get am getting frustrated that I can't since it seems so simple...

Thanks.

```
def identity(lst):
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        if i == j and lst[i][j] == 1:
                if i != j and lst[i][j] == 0:
                    return True

return False
```

I am getting false where am I going wrong?

I think I got it!!

```
def identity(lst):
size = len(lst)
for i in range(len(lst)):
    if len(lst[i]) != size:
        return False
    for j in range(len(lst)):
        if i == j and lst[i][j] != 1:
            return False
        elif i != j and lst[i][j] != 0:
            return False

return True
```

Printing the i's and j:

```
for i in range(len(lst)):
     for j in range(len(lst)):
         print("i:", i, "j:", j)
```

resulted in:

```
i: 0 j: 0
i: 0 j: 1
i: 0 j: 2
i: 1 j: 0
i: 1 j: 1
i: 1 j: 2
i: 2 j: 0
i: 2 j: 1
i: 2 j: 2
```

This really helped me a lot!

Comment: use nested loops as you mentioned and try to do all the checks inside the loops and then post what you tried in here so we can see where you got wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing first, your indentation seems broken. You should always indent correctly especially in python. It should be:

```
def identity(lst):
    for i in lst:
        for j in i:
            if i == j and lst[i][j] == 1:
                if i != j and lst[i][j] == 0:
                    return True
    return False
```

Secondly, you're not accessing the elements in the way you think you are. If I go ahead and print inside your loops with:

```
for i in lst:
    for j in i:
        print "i:", i, "j:", j
    print
```

I get:

```
i: [1, 0, 0] j: 1
i: [1, 0, 0] j: 0
i: [1, 0, 0] j: 0

i: [0, 1, 0] j: 0
i: [0, 1, 0] j: 1
i: [0, 1, 0] j: 0

i: [0, 0, 1] j: 0
i: [0, 0, 1] j: 0
i: [0, 0, 1] j: 1
```

You can use a combination of [range](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) (or [xrange](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange)) and [len](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#len) functions if you need to iterate indices of the matrix.

Lastly your conditionals doesn't make sense this way

```
if i == j and lst[i][j] == 1:
    if i != j and lst[i][j] == 0: # you never reach below here 
        return True               # because i == j is always true in here
                                  # provided by the first conditional
```

You need to seperate those conditionals. Even if you do that you'll get the a wrong answer because it will `return True` even if only one element satisfies the condition (i.e only one element is in the right place). I believe you need to think in the reverse way, `return False` in conditionals (and ofc don't forget to change them respectively) and `return True` in the end if you don't find any errors.

Let me know how you progress, I can give you more hints..

Comment: Hey i posted some more code, I think I got it!!  I think your part about printing `print "i:", i, "j:", j` really helped. When I used the range function with the len function I could really see visually the i's and the j's. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @spitfiredd glad to hear you solved it. keep in mind that you can always use a debugger instead of manual printing. you may mark an answer as accepted so it won't show up as an open question.

Comment: @spitfiredd python has its own debugger called `pdb`. it's likely that you already have it on your computer. see [this](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html).

Answer (score 1):

Since it's something you are going to use alot, you could just make it a class.

```
class Identity3(object):
  matrix = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
  def __eq__(self, other):
    return self.matrix == other
  def __new__(self):
    return [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
  def __init__(self):
    pass
```

Try using it like so,

```
>>> translate = [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 1]]
>>> translate == Identity()
False
>>> idmatrix = Identity()
>>> idmatrix
[[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: You're on the right track, but identity matrices can have *n* dimensions to them.  You could easily modify your class to accommodate that, though.

Comment: @Makoto - This is true for checking if a matrix is identity, but if you intend to pass it as an argument, you would need to know the dimensions in advance, and I've tried to cover both situations in my answer. I have some ideas, so I'll work on this and re-answer. Stay posted :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want the whole answer and only a hint: all elements on the diagonal should be 1; and the sum of all the elements in the matrix needs to be equal to the size of the diagonal.

Answer (score -1):

Just to be a bit more specific, don't forget to also check that if i != j, lst[i][j] == 0.